# How can I adjust the layout for the product page?

Tags: magento2.3

I have been able to display the SKU for the product by fixing `catalog_product_view.xml`, however, for the single product, the layout is not good. It is okay for the combo product.

[image: Look the highlighted part, the two icons is under the sku]

How can I change the layout for the single product?
Thank you.

Comment: Please explain single product and combo product.

Comment: single is just one cartridge, the combo is 4 colour cartridges for the printer

Comment: use below solution for simple and configurable products

Answer (score 0):

> To override layout for specific product type:

Magento provides various product types like Simple, Configurable, Group, Bundle, Virtual and Downloadable. Now, if you want to change product layout based on these types, then you need to override `catalog_product_view_type.xml` layout file as mentioned below.

```
catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml

catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml

catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml

catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml
```

> To override layout for just one specific product:

Create a layout file in your current theme

```
catalog_product_view_id_123.xml
```

We hereby prefer to use product ID. But in-case if that is not reliable you can use SKU  for targeting products. In that case, your layout file's  name will be in the below mention form:

```
catalog_product_view_sku_productsku.xml
```

in your case ovverides by simple and configurable layout

Comment: Can you show me the path for each file?

Comment: just copy `catalog_product_view.xml` file into the same folder and rename it.That will override layout product type wise

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it in different way